# The exe package CLion created cannot be ran

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

When I try to run the `exe` package that `CLion` created, I got an error: `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll not found`.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: The way to fix that is to make sure that `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll` is found.  You probably want to start off by adding your compiler's bin folder to the `PATH` environment variable which will tell your OS where to look for that dll. This document describes how your OS searches for dependent dlls: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-for-desktop-applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-for-desktop-applications)

Comment: are you using windows?

Comment: @bzkn Yes, I am using windows

Comment: @drescherjm I checked `PATH` and found my compiler's bin path in it. So should I add the path for `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll` to `PATH` too？

Comment: That file should be in the bin folder for your compiler. Remember we are talking about the compiler not Clion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MingW to compile C++ code on Windows, you may like to add the option `-static-libstdc++` to link the C++ standard libraries statically. What exactly I mean is following:

- For instance adding `set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static")` to your cmake file may fix it.

Additionally please also make sure you have set the environment variable correctly for MinGW in your Windows environment variable section. What exactly I mean is following:

- `C:\MinGW\bin` to your system `PATH` variable